# I am using Android Studio, and, even after installing genymotion unable to set path

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio and installed `genymotion`, but I'm not getting path of genymotion.

I've tried this path, but it's not working. (Using Windows 7).

```
C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to Genymotion settings and under ADB select **use custom SDK** and put the path to where your android sdk is installed. If you have insalled sdk from android sdk manager than it should be in: **"C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk"**